# Linking non C99 static library in C99 mode

Tags: c, gcc, static-libraries, c99

I have a static library which I compiled with gcc without c99 mode. I am trying to link it in compilation using gcc -std=c99. This is giving me an error:

`undefined reference to 'functionName'`

Here, functionName is function inside the static library.

This is my compilation:

```
gcc -std=c99 -g -I../ -Llib/ -lmylib test.c ../file1.c ../file2.c -o test
```

I am using C99 here because my code in test.c #includes header files whose implementation uses C99 standard.

The static library(lib/libmylib.a) in not compiled with c99 standard because it's code uses some libraries which are failing to compile in C99 mode(but compiles without c99 flag).

I also tried changing the order of the -L & -l flags to the end & immediately after gcc -std=c99 but it gave the same 'undefined reference' error.

How do I link these together?

Thank you.

**EDIT**: The function which I've mentioned as `functionName` is a pseudonym for setupStacktrace() shown here: http://pastebin.com/2RbEEPaj. It is signature is `void setupStacktrace();`

Comment: Are you certain that `functionName` is defined in one of the source files/library, and that it isn't defined `inline`?

Comment: Libraries after object files!  Try: `gcc -std=c99 -g -I../ -Llib/ test.c ../file1.c ../file2.c -lmylib -o test`

Comment: @Casey that `functionName` is inside the static library. Will edit the question to add clarity.

Comment: Add the declaration of `functionName` to the question, please. (C99 does some interesting things with `inline`)

Comment: @Casey, its not an inline function. I've edited my question with the function definition.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I tried this order & its the same error. I suspect it might have something to so with c99 mode since I created another test program which does not import headers with c99 style. This program just calls the method from the static library. I compiled this with plain gcc without -std=c99 and it worked.

Comment: Have you run `nm -g lib/libmylib.a` and checked that the function really is there?  Have you verified that it really is searching your library? (Try moving the library: `mv lib/libmylib.a lib/old.libmylib.a` and then run the link again.  It should fail to find the library.)  I've not heard of any C89 vs C99 problems; I would not expect there to be any.  If there are, `inline` functions are about the only likely cause, and I'm not really sure how that would happen.  I suppose a non-inlined function reference might be missing, but you said that isn't the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the command line arguments matter. The way you have it now, the linker goes through your static libraries, realizes that nothing so far need anything it provides, and throw away everything in it. Do this:

```
gcc -std=c99 -g -I../ -Llib/  test.c ../file1.c ../file2.c -lmylib -o test
```

Comment: as I've mentioned in a comment under my question, I tried this order yet it's failing :(

Comment: @RBK then something else is wrong, such as the function does not exist in your static library (run the `nm` tool on your static library and see which functions it contains), you've spelled the name wrong, you're iinking in some other `mylib` than what you think you do,  or something else you havn't told us is going on. This is not an issue with linking to code that is not C99 (unless you've compiled it with a C++ compiler).

Comment: Thanks! There were 2 issues - as you said I had misspelled the name of the function. Fixed that. Also had to put the -lmylib before the -o. Didn't work otherwise. Sorry for the delay in getting back as I didn't have access to my work machine over the weekend.